# Double summation of elementary functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial, exponentiation

I am finding some trouble on calculating the following double summation:

$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{(b*x)^n}{(n-1)!}
$

Note that the inside sum gives:
$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{(b*x)^n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{b*x*e^{bx}Γ(k-1,bx)}{Γ(k-1)}$

But I cannot simplify the second sum as well. Any ideas?